# Has scholarship shown that persecuted religious minorities have tended to be financially successful?

Tags: religion, economy, finance

In [this interview](http://www.salon.com/2004/04/21/stephenson_4/) with Neal Stephenson, talking about the historical basis for his *Baroque Cycle* series of novels, he makes the remark that

> ... persecuted religious minorities, if they’re not persecuted out of existence, often manage to achieve disproportionate wealth. It happened with Jews, Armenians, Huguenots. Earlier in this project, I could have rattled off five more

Is there any evidence for this statement? What are other historical examples of persecuted religious minorities who have become financially successful as a result of their persecution?

If there is evidence that the statement is true, then what are the proposed explanations?

Comment: Yes, I think there is lot's of historic evidence (e.g. also from Chinese history), but being persecuted alone certainly does not determine/cause financial success. You e.g. "need" oppressors that drive/allow a minority into professions that oppressors (at the time) despise or neglect yet that can (with skill, hard work, luck, etc.) be turned into financial success over time. IMHO some (even many) persecuted minorities have tended to be financially successful, but to say that all "tended to" is much too strong/general a statement.

Comment: Define economic success for a minority, and apply this to actual data on social conditions. For example, the large majority of Jews in Poland prior to WWII lived very precarious lives, while at the same time beeing thought of as financially succesful. I think Graeber in "Debt: the first 5000 years" makea similiar argument about the Jews in medivial England.

Comment: Christian Church (took them a couple of centuries though).

Comment: I agree with @mart. You need to be able to clearly show a difference between "**most successful members** of a minority community are financially successful" as opposed to "**entire** community is financially successful" (e.g look at a mode; or a mean+standard deviation; as opposed to just mean), for any of those examples to be true.

Comment: Drux has it backwards, it is often the financially successful minorities who end up persecuted, their religion (or whatever else sets them apart) being used as an excuse.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any evidence for this statement?

No.  It is clearly falsifiable and falsified—see the experience of indigenous people in settler societies.  (Think Canada, US, Australia, New Zealand, Argentina, Chile).

Comment: And we can mention the gipsy population in eastern europe, they live generally in the lowest living standards in Romania, Hungary, Serbia.

Comment: Counterexamples are insufficient to prove/disprove a tendency. OP asked for further examples and for evidence/explanation.

Comment: -1 - none of those are persecuted **religious** minorities which is what Stephenson was talking about. Neither are Gypsies.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace A five society counter example overcomes a claim of "often", see NeilStephenson, "if they’re not persecuted out of existence, often"

Comment: @DVK the question regards "minorities" in general.  Perhaps a better specification for the conditional is required, "Minorities internal to the centre of a world-system," well, sure, except we've got the Irish.  "Religious minorities internal to the centre of a world-system," well, except Albanians, and Croats, and Serbs, and Catholic Dissent in England.  Stephenson is being extremely lazy and so is this hypothesis.  All of the communities Stephenson is looking at had both a diaspora and urbanisation, with capital dependency for survival in feudalism.  Lazy theorisation is lazy.

Comment: @SamuelRussell - no. The question reads precisely: "What are other historical examples of **persecuted** religious minorities...". I don't know what Stephenson's examples were, I just know what the question asks. And it doesn't include aborigines being oppressed for... well being aborigines (even if they convert to Christianity as was the case with many native americans)

Comment: @DVK If you feel that the title of a question doesn't reflect a question you might edit it.

Comment: @SamuelRussell - ah. I didn't realize that the title omitted the word "religious" - I was just reading the body.

Comment: @DVK [meta: Ought we more efficiently make the question title match the substantive question?](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/482/ought-we-more-efficiently-make-the-question-title-match-the-substantive-question)

Comment: @SamuelRussell - no argument there :) I just don't usually pay as much attention to subjects as to bodies if the question's already open :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a relevant example concerning the Jewish minority in late 19th-century Vienna, as recorded by [Peter Gay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Gay) in *Freud: A Life for Our Time*:

> Many of the immigrants from the miserable villages to the east dressed
>   and spoke and gestured in ways alien and disagreeable to the Viennese;
>   they were too exotic to be familiar and not exotic enough to be
>   charming. They came as peddlers and small shopkeepers, but many of
>   their sons entered callings vulnerable to bigoted criticism and easy
>   slander: banking, or wholesale trading, or journalism. By the 1880s,
>   at lead half of Viennese journalists, physicians, and lawyers where
>   Jews. [Sigmund] Freud at Gymnasium contemplating either a legal or a medical
>   career was being perfectly conventional. That is what many young Jews
>   in Vienna did. Demonstrating their proverbial appetite for learning,
>   they poured into Vienna's educational institutions and, concentrated as
>   they were in a few districts, clustered in a few schools until their
>   classes resembled extended family clans. During the eight years that
>   Freud attended his Gymnasium, between 1865 and 1873, the number of
>   Jewis students there increased from 68 to 300, rising from 44 to 73
>   percent of the tool school population.

IMO the phenomenon is clearly not restricted to Jews and to followers of the Abrahamic religions alone (as suggested in another answer): To some extent it e.g. also applies to Chinese minorities in countries such as Indonesia (as I know from a friend's family history), to Indians in Africa ([V.S. Naipaul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naipaul)'s novel *A Bend in the River* conveys a bit of that), and to Asian-American students excelling in top graduate schools today (let's not forget that their forefathers once were also confined to "persecuted minorities").

Answer (score 2):

The [Chinese minority in Indonesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Indonesian#Managing_the_.22Chinese_Problem.22_.281967.E2.80.931998.29) is the first supporting example that comes to mind. However worldwide it is far more common for oppressed ethnic minorities to be relatively poor due to the legal and social barriers they have to deal with.

I love Neal Stevenson's work (particularly the Baroque Cycle), but like many authors he's got his annoying quirks. In this case he's made the classic error of believing the plural of anecdote is "data".

Comment: Most ethnic minorities are NOT oppressed over religion.

Comment: though religion may be used as a spark or excuse for persecution, something that sets those groups apart, makes them "weird", "heretics", etc.

Comment: @DVK - I'm really confused now. Where did I mention religon in this?

Comment: @T.E.D. - the OP asked about minorities persecuted **for their religion**, not persecuted in general (e.g. for ethnic reasons)

Comment: @DVK - Ah. Well, I guess I'm agreeing with you then. However, it is quite common for ethnic minorities to pick up a miniority religon too in order to help keep their cultural identity separate (eg: Christianity in non-Indonesian East Timor), so the waters can get really muddy there.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would say "no".  The exception of course being the Abrahamic religions Judaism, Christianity and Islam, which prohibits taking advantage of "brothers" (those with the same faith) by charging interest - this obvious opened up a nisce for minorities of other faiths.

But it's not as clear cut, as - to take Europe - Jews didn't only lend money to Christians, there were also Christians who let money to Jews... the important thing, was not to lend to people of your own faith.  Of course since there were fewer Jews in Europe than Christians, the wealth from this where most obviously accumulated among the relatively few Jews.

Minorities were often heavily taxed - both Jews in Christian Europe and non-muslims under Islam.  Further more, minorities risked having their whole fortune sieced, being arrested or expelled.

If you look at other minorities - especially non-religious or at least not Jews or Christians - they have not fared well at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yale Professor Amy Chua makes this case for Russian Jews, Yugoslav Croats, Chinese in Southeast Asia and others, in this book http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_on_Fire

Note, however, that she is also the author of  "Battle Hymn of the Tiger Mother."

Comment: I think the claim regarding Croatians is as dubious as the claim regarding Western European Jews.  Both populations had internal stratification.  The Court Jew was emblematic of the misery of the mass of late feudal and early modern Jews in Germany.  The mass of Croatians were involved in agricultural Feudalism under which ever house controlled the region.

Answer (score 0):

I think Stephenson has the cart leading the horse here.

Take the Jews of Western Europe (Jews in Eastern Europe were emphatically not well off). The Jews did not became wealthy because they were persecuted. To a large extent, they became wealthy because they could be bankers (and could loan money, even if not formally bankers) at a time when Christians were forbidden to be, because of the Church's attitude was that usury was sinful.  Their subsequent wealth led to further discrimination.